# Why does Verilog output show x and z instead of zero and 1?

Tags: verilog, fpga, shift-register

I am modelling a shift register consisting of three D flip flops. There are three inputs (clk, reset, shiftIn) and one output (shiftOut). The reset is synchronous active high and resets all the flip flops.

Design

```
    module shiftReg(shiftIn,clk,reset,shiftOut);
    input shiftIn, clk, reset;
    output shiftOut;
    reg Q1,Q2,shiftOut;
    always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) 
    begin
        if(reset == 1'b1) begin
            Q1 <= 1'b0;
            Q2 <= 1'b0;
            shiftOut <= 1'b0;
        end
        else begin
            Q1 <= shiftIn;
            Q2 <= Q1;
            shiftOut <= Q2;
        end
    end
    endmodule
```

testbench

```
    module tb_shiftReg();
    reg shiftin;
    reg clk;
    reg reset;
    wire shiftOut;
    shiftReg SR(shiftIn,clk,reset,shiftOut);
    initial begin
        clk=0;
        forever #10 clk = ~clk; 
    end
    initial begin
        $monitor("time=",$time, "shiftin=%b  reset =%d shiftout =%b",shiftIn,reset,shiftOut);
        $dumpfile("test.vcd");
        $dumpvars;           
        reset=0;
        shiftin <= 0;
        #100;
        reset=0;
        shiftin <= 1;
        #100;
        reset =1;
        shiftin <= 0;
        #100;
        reset =1;
        shiftin <= 0;
        #100 $finish;
    end
    endmodule
```

I am getting the following as output when I simulate it using `iverilog`:

```
    vu2swz@PPDP01:~$ iverilog Shiftregister.v 
    vu2swz@PPDP01:~$ ./a.out 
    VCD info: dumpfile test.vcd opened for output.
    time=                   0shiftin=z  reset =0 shiftout =x
    time=                  50shiftin=z  reset =0 shiftout =z
    time=                 200shiftin=z  reset =1 shiftout =0
```

Why am I getting z and x instead of 1 and zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verilog is case-sensitive.  `shiftin` is a different signal from `shiftIn` (capital "I").  In the testbench you declared `shiftin`, but you did not declare `shiftIn`.  By default Verilog considers undeclared signals as type `wire`, and the default value of a `wire` is `z`.  This means that the input to your design module is undriven.  The simulator I used gave me a warning message about this.  You can also try your code on different simulators on edaplayground to get more helpful messages.

Change all `shiftIn` to `shiftin` in your testbench module, and that clears up most of your `z` and `x`:

```
time=                   0shiftin=0  reset =0 shiftout =x
time=                  50shiftin=0  reset =0 shiftout =0
time=                 100shiftin=1  reset =0 shiftout =0
time=                 150shiftin=1  reset =0 shiftout =1
time=                 200shiftin=0  reset =1 shiftout =0
```

You still get `x` at time 0 because reset is not asserted at time 0; reset is asserted at time 200.  Typically, you would assert reset at time 0 (`reset=1;`), then deassert it (`reset=0;`) after a few clock cycles, say at time 100.

```
module tb_shiftReg();
    reg shiftin;
    reg clk;
    reg reset;
    wire shiftOut;
    shiftReg SR(shiftin,clk,reset,shiftOut);
    initial begin
        clk=0;
        forever #10 clk = ~clk; 
    end
    initial begin
        $monitor("time=",$time, "shiftin=%b  reset =%d shiftout =%b",shiftin,reset,shiftOut);
        $dumpfile("test.vcd");
        $dumpvars;           
        reset=1;
        shiftin <= 0;
        #100;
        reset=0;
        shiftin <= 1;
        #100;
        shiftin <= 0;
        #100;
        shiftin <= 0;
        #100 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

With the above changes, all signals show 0/1:

```
time=                   0shiftin=0  reset =1 shiftout =0
time=                 100shiftin=1  reset =0 shiftout =0
time=                 150shiftin=1  reset =0 shiftout =1
time=                 200shiftin=0  reset =0 shiftout =1
time=                 250shiftin=0  reset =0 shiftout =0
```

---

Note: Your reset signal is *asynchronous*, not *synchronous*, because you included `reset` in the sensitivity list:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
```